# Make an Erlang app release on a Mac to run it on Linux?

Tags: erlang

Are releases cross-platform so that I can build a release on one platform, and run it as it is on another or should I build on the same platform on which I am going to run the app?

Answer (score 3):

Releases mechanism requires at least additional work to be made to make it cross-platform

While Erlang `beams` are cross-platform, releases usually contain additional data that can be platform dependent.

It is

- Erts itself.
- Platform dependent libraries

If you want to build release for Linux at Mac, you'll at least will need Erts build for Linux. If you are using `relx`, for example, you'll have to [specify](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases#cross-compiling) it with

```
{include_erts, "/path/to/erlang"},
{system_libs, "/path/to/erlang"},
```

Additional platform-dependent libraries is a different story. Almost every complicated Erlang application use some NIFs or Ports, that are usually come with release and sit in `priv`s. If you use any, you'll have to cross-compile them for your target platform. You'll have to handle it by yourself probably

Answer (score 1):

Provided that those platforms have same OTP version: Yes `.beam` files should be compatible across platforms because it's the Erlang VM that interprets the bytecode. Just like `.class` files and JVM.

For platforms with different versions, it's backwards compatible with 2 major releases. Means if you made a release on a OS X machine with R16B, it should be compatible to any machines running OTP 17 and 18. [Source](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-June/059463.html)

Both cases however doesn't apply to compiled native code or NIFs.